# How can I properly use variables returned in other function / method?

Tags: python, function, methods

Please bare with me since I am just starting to learn coding, and Python is my first language to go.
I struggle and can't really get to understand how the functions work.
I can't manage to call it and use later on when I need it in another function.

Can someone please help me understand the depth of it ?

My code doesn't work and I can't manage to understand how to grab the results from a function, in order to use those results for the end purpose.

This is something I tried in the project I am working on:

```
manly_coded_bag = []
female_coded_bag = []

feminine_coded_words = [
    "agree",
    "affectionate",
    "child",
    "cheer",
]

masculine_coded_words = [
    "active",
    "adventurous",
    "aggressive",
    "ambitios",
]

explanations = {
    "feminine-coded": (
        "This job ad uses more words that are subtly coded as feminine than words that are subtly coded as masculine"
    ),
    "masculine-coded": (
        "This job ad uses more words that are subtly coded as masculine than words that are subtly coded as feminine."
    )


def men_coded_words(masc_bag, text):
    add_text = text
    man_coded_bag = masc_bag
    for word in masculine_coded_words:
        if word in add_text:
            man_coded_bag.append(word)    
    return man_coded_bag


def women_coded_words(fem_bag, text):
    add_text = text
    woman_coded_bag = fem_bag
    for word in feminine_coded_words:
        if word in add_text:
            woman_coded_bag.append(word)
    return woman_coded_bag


def analise_and_explain_results(text, count_man, count_fem):
 
    count_man_words = count_man
    count_man_words = len(man_coded_bag)

    count_woman_words = count_fem
    count_woman_words = len(woman_coded_bag)

    coding_score = count_woman_words - count_man_words

    strengths_of_coding = ""

    if coding_score == 0:
        if count_man_words:
            strengths_of_coding = "neutral"
        else:
            strengths_of_coding = "empty"
    elif coding_score > 0:
        strengths_of_coding = "feminine-coded"
    else:
        strengths_of_coding = "masculine-coded"

    return count_man_words, count_woman_words, strengths_of_coding


def get_results(text):
    user_input = text
    user_input = input("add text here:").lower()

    res = analise_and_explain_results(text, man_coded_bag, 
    woman_coded_bag)


    # i am trying to use the returned variable strengths_of_coding and 
    is not accesible.
    explain_results = explanations[strengths_of_coding]

    return res, explain_results

get_results("random text added here, really whatever for testing purposes")
```

Right, so when I am calling get_results('text'), I get this error and I know where it is coming from, "name 'strengths_of_coding' is not defined", but I just don't know how to access that variable...
I'm stuck here and a little bit frustrated because I understand it's a noob mistake, yet still I can't get the hang of it after a week of stress and frustration.

Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: i dont see your code where you are calling get_results...

Comment: it is right after the last line of code, I  will edit my post and add that one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's hard to explain everything if you barely have any knowledge in OOP or coding in general. But in python, the return value of a function can be anything. `None`, a integer, a list, tuple, dictionary, object. Can even be a class definition. Only by looking at it, will you know exactly. That is called duck-typing; "If it walks like a duck and it quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck"

In this case, your `analise_and_explain_results` function does not return *one* thing, but several since it does this:

```
return count_man_words, count_woman_words, strengths_of_coding
```

So it actually returns a tuple with those three values inside. And these variables are *scoped* to that specific function, you cannot use them outside that function anymore. *Note*: For the sake of simplicity; let's just stick to not using them outside of the function since it's bad practice.

In your code, you then do this:

```
res = analise_and_explain_results(user_input, man_coded_bag, woman_coded_bag)
```

Which means that `res` at this point is actually the tuple holding the three values you are interested in. You have several ways to resolve this. But this easiest to follow is to just assign the values of variables like this:

```
count_man_words, count_woman_words, strengths_of_coding = analise_and_explain_results(user_input, man_coded_bag, woman_coded_bag)
```

This basically *unpacks* the tuple into three different values since it basically does this:

```
a, b, c = (1, 2 ,3)
```

Where before you did:

```
d = (1, 2, 3)
```

Unpacking is easy, as long as the item you unpack holds as many items as you're trying to assign;

```
a, b, c = d
```

If you have trouble grasping OOP and python I would suggest you learn to walk, before you run, which you're doing now IMO.
Follow some tutorials or videos explaining OOP and python. Or combine them like they do on [realpython](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/).

Comment: Thank you, your feedback is valuable. 
I want to pack all the variables in a json object and return them for the front end to highlight the words in the text and stuff like that, so I need all of them.  I understand better how to use them thanks to your comment.

Comment: After I used your guidance to fix my error, came back here trying to explain to you what is actually the answer I am looking for, and I ended up looking from a different perspective while formulating my question as clearly as possible. While doing so I managed to see where my understanding on functions needed to be clarified. Your comment helped me fix my error, look at functions from a different perspective, and this led me to find some other answers that I was looking for.
I will mark it as the right answer, but I don't have enough reputation to upvote it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

`strengths_of_coding` is only defined inside the `analise_and_explain_results` function. When you return the values of that function, they are no longer attached to the names you used inside the function

`return count_man_words, count_woman_words, strengths_of_coding` can be also written as `return (count_man_words, count_woman_words, strengths_of_coding)` - it means the return value of the function is a tuple with 3 elements that are values of each of the variables, and that tuple is assigned to `res` in `res = analise_and_explain_results(user_input, man_coded_bag, woman_coded_bag)`

Value of variable called `strengths_of_coding` inside the function is available as `res[2]` in `get_results` after you do the assignment to `res`

Answer (score 0):

`res = analise_and_explain_results(user_input, man_coded_bag, woman_coded_bag)` turns `res` into a tuple with 3 elements. `strengths_of_coding` is the 3rd element in this tuple. So, you access it as `res[2]`. In python, when you return multiple stuff to one variable, the variable turns into a tuple. You can provide multiple variables to take each return. e,g, `count_man_words, count_woman_words, strengths_of_coding = analise_and_explain_results(user_input, man_coded_bag, woman_coded_bag)`. Or, if you only need that one return then, `strengths_of_coding = analise_and_explain_results(user_input, man_coded_bag, woman_coded_bag)[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a late answer. This is how I ended up fixing my code with the kind help from people who answered, I have came to understand where I was making mistakes.
This is how I fixed my code, using the example above, just in case someone else  struggle with grasping the basics.

As a bonus for any new beginner finding this useful, something I learned from someone else.
The last print statement is a very useful way to debug your code:

```
print("results are: %s" % results)
```

For example adding it at the end, you can see if you ended up getting the right results, like in my example, or you can add it in your code to see what results you return in each functions and so on.

```
user_input = "Active, child, whatever random text, testing"
text = user_input.lower()

# declare the coded words, feminine and masculine
feminine_coded_words = [
    "agree",
    "affectionate",
    "child",
    "cheer",
]

masculine_coded_words = [
    "active",
    "adventurous",
    "aggressive",
    "ambitios",
]

# declare explanations to use when we explain the results to the user.
explanations = {
    "feminine-coded": (
        "This job ad uses more words that are subtly coded as feminine than words that are subtly coded as masculine"
    ),
    "masculine-coded": (
        "This job ad uses more words that are subtly coded as masculine than words that are subtly coded as feminine."
    ),
    "neutral": ("this is neutral"),
    "empty": ("empty text"),
}


# initiate two empty variable where we add our coded words, when we find them.


def men_coded_words(text):
    add_text = text
    manly_coded_bag = []
    for word in masculine_coded_words:
        if word in add_text:
            manly_coded_bag.append(word)
    return manly_coded_bag


def women_coded_words(text):
    add_text = text
    feminine_coded_bag = []
    for word in feminine_coded_words:
        if word in add_text:
            feminine_coded_bag.append(word)
    return feminine_coded_bag


def feminine_counted_words(text):
    woman_coded_bag = women_coded_words(text)
    return len(woman_coded_bag)


def masculine_counted_words(text):
    man_coded_bag = men_coded_words(text)
    return len(man_coded_bag)


def coding_score(text):
    count_fem_words = feminine_counted_words(text)
    count_masc_words = masculine_counted_words(text)
    return count_fem_words - count_masc_words


def explain_results(text):
    strengths_of_coding = ""
    count_masc_words = masculine_counted_words(text)
    coding_score_results = coding_score(text)

    if coding_score_results == 0:
        if count_masc_words:
            strengths_of_coding = "neutral"
        else:
            strengths_of_coding = "empty"
    elif coding_score_results > 0:
        strengths_of_coding = "feminine-coded"
    else:
        strengths_of_coding = "masculine-coded"

    return strengths_of_coding


def get_results(text):
    strenght_of_coding = explain_results(text)

    return explanations[strenght_of_coding]


results = get_results(text)

print("results are: %s" % results)
```